# Android Studio - Button Click Crash (Simple)

Tags: android

I'm brand new to Android Studio and for whatever reason am experiencing really weird errors if I could please get some help.

I have very basic code that is supposed to, on button click change the text of my button from "button" to "clicked!". However everytime I press the button, the app crashes and I get "Appname has stopped" on the emulator.

What is incredibly weird is that in my activity_main.xml Design view, the onClick dropdown shows two functions of the same name (https://puu.sh/t2h5I/42ad4379d6.png)

H owever the code only works when the bottom one is selected. AND each time I run the app, it deselects the bottom one and reselects the top, only to stop working.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.john.ameladay;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button melButtonCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonPress(View v){
        melButtonCode = (Button) v;
        ((Button) v).setText("Has been clicked!");

    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.john.ameladay.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mainText"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mela"
    android:id="@+id/melPhoto" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonPress (MainActivity)" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please Share Crash report

Comment: Where are you calling buttonPress function?

Comment: use onclicklistner instead of onclick and show toast or anything on your button click like this:

Comment: and first find the id of your button

Comment: melButtonCode = (Button) findviewbyid(R.id.button);

Comment: Do you know accepting an answer...? You can accept one helpful answer. For more information, see help center

Answer (score 2):

**Simple.** You should write:

```
android:onClick="buttonPress"
```

## Why happened

If you wrote `buttonPress (MainActivity)`, Android tries to find `buttonPress (MainActivity)` method (not `MainActivity.buttonPress()`), but MainActivity doesn't have `buttonPress (MainActivity)` method. So the error happened.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this Tag in button

**Remove this**

```
android:onClick="buttonPress (MainActivity)"
```

**And Paste This**

```
android:onClick="buttonPress"
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it is, get a reference to the button in your Java code using `findViewById()` method and set an `OnClickListener` to the button.

For your current problem, use

```
android:onClick="buttonPress"
```

instead of

```
android:onClick="buttonPress (MainActivity)"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me **this is the better way to set click on button**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button melButtonCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        melButtonCode = (Button).findViewById(R.id.button);//find button by Id
        melButtonCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                melButtonCode.setText("Has been clicked!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**For your problem**

**replace it**

```
android:onClick="buttonPress (MainActivity)"
```

**With**

```
android:onClick="buttonPress"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the method public - protected works when you are in instantrun mode, but not when not. No idea why!

Comment: _Which_ method should be made public?

Comment: Consider adding some code describing which method to make public.